# How can I append to the system path for Maven Surefire tests that use DLLs?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I'd like to be able to append a lib directory to the system path to allow Maven to run unit tests that (gah) use DLL native libraries.

I have so far used `<argLine>-Djava.library.path=${path.dll}</argLine>` to add my DLL path as a library path. However, Windows still wants to resolve DLLs via the path, and I'm getting:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

So, is there a way of providing a modified system path to Surefire?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What you're telling should work. Can you provide more context, e.g. your full surefire configuration? Also, is path.dll a directory, and if so, in what form are you defining it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the following config was necessary:

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> 
  <configuration> 
    ...
    <environmentVariables> 
      <PATH>${basedir}\..;${java.library.path}</PATH> 
    </environmentVariables> 
    ...
  </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: awesome, but to be platform independent, dont hardocde semi colon - ${java.library.path}${path.separator}${env.WORKSPACE}\abc

Comment: It seems that this no longer works with version 3 of the failsafe plugin